# A vector space V is an irreducible End(V)-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

> Let $V$ be a nonzero vector space. I consider $V$ as an $\operatorname{End}(V)$-module. Then it is irreducible.

My thoughts:
Let $U$ be a nonzero submodule of $V$ and $u\in U-\{0\}$. I want to show that $U=V$. Let $v\in V-\{0\}$.
How can I guarantee that there is $f\in\operatorname{End}(V)$ such that $f(u)=v$? Thanks!

Comment: Are you assuming $V$ to be finite dimensional?

Comment: No, but I also wonder the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Hint: Pick a basis of $V$ such that the first two elements are $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @MattPressland How will it fail in the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I understand something wrong. Here v is arbitrary so u and v can be linearly dependent. How can I pick a basis including u and v?

Comment: The case where they are linearly dependent is the easier one, which I decided to let you handle yourself

Comment: @MattPressland Note that we are just proving that the action of the endomorphism group is transitive. And I mean basis as in "basis of a vector space" (I guess to make the argument easy you need to well-order the basis).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Now I see, thank you very much for your hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

A nonzero $R$-module $M$ is simple iff for all nonzero $x,y\in M$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $xr=y$.

Do you believe that given any two nonzero vectors $v,w$ you are able to find a linear tranformation sending $v$ to $w$?

Comment: To answer this question, I try to use Tobias' hint.

Comment: This hint is meant to complement Tobias's hint.

Comment: If v and w are linearly dependent, then w=$\lambda$v for some $\lambda$ in the field. So there is f$\in$End(V) such that f(x)=$\lambda$x. So we can find a such a linear transformation. But if they are linearly independent, still I could not see the answer.

Comment: @ErginSuer If $\beta$ is a basis of $V$ and $W$ is any vector space, then you know the property of bases that *any* function from $\beta$ into $W$ extends uniquely to a linear transformation of $V$ into $W$, right?

Comment: You are right. Thank you very much!